# Comparing CPU across different generations

Tags: cpu

So. My friend asked me to just improve performance of his computer, but I found a little issue. I found out that CPU is the bottlenecker, when I was about to order better CPU (3rd gen - the same gen as previous, but higher clock and i5), I found less powerful i5, but it was 8th gen. The difference is not as big, but I'm curious, how can I compare those?

Comment: Checkout CPU benchmarks, like these: https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php

Comment: CPUBenchmark.net is definately the "go-to" place for an overview of relative performance boiled down to 1 number.  If you want to get into the weeds once you have this overview, head on over to ark.intel.com to compare the functionality of the CPUs.

Comment: Any 8th generation Core processor is incompatible with any 3rd Core generation core processor hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare passmark CPU scores here 
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleCompare.php

Unfortunately the 8th generation uses different socket. The latest generation with 1155 socket you can get is 7th.

So if you replaced i3-3225 with i3-7350K

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i3-3225-vs-Intel-i3-7350K/1474vs2930

you would get ~50% increase.

Comment: It is more appropriate to link the the site that generates these benchmarks, rather then a reseller that happens to list some of them - ie cpubenchmark.net.

Comment: Sure, I will edit it.

Comment: Yeah, that is possible answear, and yeah, I noticed the different socket later, but anyhow, a website can't just tell me if it is really like that I think. Is there any kind of database of comparison from real-computer benchmarks for CPUs? I'm so tired by looking for every result thorugh whole internet. I would preffer results from Cinebench, but I couldn't find any site with results

Comment: @arty cpubenchmark.net is exactly "a database of comparison from real-computer benchmarks for CPUs"